# Will these RAM work together?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I'm planning on upgrading my PC's RAM. My current RAM is a Kingston 8GB DDR3 stick. Further specifications are in the images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l0mc.jpg

Anyway, I'm planning on buying a Kingston HyperX Fury 8GB DDR3 1600Mhz stick as my second RAM stick; http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX316C10FB_8.pdf

Will both of these RAM work together in dual-channel mode just fine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the specs of the MOBO here... I think it'll work but check all the specs to compare and consider reaching out to the seller or the MOBO manufacturer to confirm.... https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/H81MD/specifications/... The specs show `2 x DIMM, Max. 16GB, DDR3 1600/1333/1066 MHz Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory` and state 16 GB max...also look over the `2 x DIMM, Max. 16GB, DDR3 1600/1333/1066 MHz Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory` and `* Hyper DIMM support is subject to the physical characteristics of individual CPUs` aspects as mentioned for **Memory**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would buy the exact same stick that you already have again to be 100% sure that it will work.

> Well RAM is sold in kits for a reason. Some motherboards react very
>   sensitive to this and that is also the reason why the vendors do not
>   support RAM that is not bought in one kit.
>
> Altough, I think the problem with newer intel chipsets is less. But I
>   would choose the safer path by buying RAM in one kit instead of loose
>   sticks. You can try to put in that 8GB HyperX but the ram should have
>   the same voltage, speed and cas numbers.

However some things changed. The 3 most critical things that should match are Timings, CAS latency and Voltage. If you have 2 ram of different speeds they will adjust to the ram at the lowest speed. I personally would't risk it and buy 1 of the exact same RAM that you already have.

[source](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1823033/matching-ram.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I think I may just go back to my same memory stick. Will it have a big difference in performance, as in is the HyperX Fury better than my current RAM stick? The spec sheet is here: http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR16N11_8.pdf

Comment: @EdwardKris Memory has different speeds. Speccy does not really give an accurate Mhz speed. DDR3- has different speeds. 1333, 1600, 1866, 2400. As you can see the Kingston HyperX Fury 8GB DDR3 1600Mhz runs at 1600Mhz. If your old memory has 1600Mhz or higher it will run as fast as the "new" one. If not it is slower but only a little.

Comment: I have seen that CPU-Z gives us a DRAM speed. This is usually the bios speed the memory runs at. You do that times two and you will get roughly ~1600 Mhz. So I think your memory runs at 1600 Mhz which means its as fast as the HyperX.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that both Speccy and CPU-Z give the speed in half. Both have it at 799Mhz, doubled makes it 1600Mhz, which is the speed of my RAM if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, I'll more than likely go for the same memory stick.